# Why crystal report is not showing anything in Asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net

I have first created dataset & then created crystal report.I have attached that crystal report to web form ,but after running that webform crystal report is not showing any output.Please help me to get output.
I am using visual studio 2013.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"));
        DataSet dsCustomers = GetData("select * from customers");
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    }

    private DataSet GetData(string query)
    {
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet dsCustomers = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "DataTable1");
                    return dsCustomers;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try calling DataBind in your page load to see if autobinding is not working as you intend?

Answer (score 1):

Looks you are missing databind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"));
    DataSet dsCustomers = GetData("select * from customers");
    crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
    CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: There's a comment from @Nikki9696 that says the same but an hour before you did, so your post should not be considered as accepted answer.

Comment: Still Not getting output

Comment: Please make sure your dataset dsCustomers has rows